# How to read a array like structure and make a key-value pair as specified? P.S Please check body for better explaination of query

Tags: java, arrays, string, google-bigquery

```
[
target {
  column: "marks"
}
parents {
  table {
    kind: BIGQUERY_TABLE
    sqlResource: "bigquery.table.location"
  }
}

, 

target {
  column: "name"
}
parents {
  table {
    kind: BIGQUERY_TABLE
    sqlResource: "bigquery.table.location"
    
  }
}
]
```

It is an array like input (comma separated) and I want to read the column(as specified under 'target:column' from a bigquery table (location of bqtable in 'parent:table:sqlResource' and store them in a key-value pair. How should it be done?
I tried it using if-else conditions and I feel there should be a efficient way to do this?
Please let me know a better solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two parts in your question:

1. How to parse the String you provided
2. How to used parsed info

I will answer the first part. The String you provided looks like a JSON string, but it is an invalid JSON. After keys "target", "parents" and "table" there must be symbol ":". That will make it a valid JSON. Assuming that you have this. You can parse your JSON using any of available JSON libraries (notably [Json-Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), (Maven artifacts [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind)) or [Gson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5)). I wrote my own open source library called MgntUtils, that has JSON parser based on Json-Jackson. Using this library you can easily parse your JSON String into List of Maps

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = null;
try {
      list = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(jsonString, List.class);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
   ...
}
```

Your list will contain two Map elements where under the key "target" you will have a map with key "column" and its value and so forth. Here is the relevant [Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). The MgntUtils Maven artifacts could be found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) and Github project with source code and javadoc is [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases)